# Python: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 in statement from if else conditional statement

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements, valueerror

I feel like I'm missing something foolish here, but I can't find an answer in stackoverflow or anywhere else that quite fits what I'm seeing nor fixes my issue.

I have a dictionary and I'm simply checking to see if a specific key exists. If it does not exist then I add the key and value to the dictionary.

Example code:

```
test_dict = {
        'commit_msg': 'some_message', 
        'some_version': '12345', 
        'test_id': '12345'
}

if 'some_key' in test_dict:
    print("True")
else:
    test_dict['some_key'] = 'some_value'
```

Simple thing right?

If I run the following line in debugger:

```
'some_key' in test_dict
```

...this will return a result of false.

If I also run the following in the debugger:

```
test_dict['some_key'] = 'some_value'
```

...this will add the key and value to test_dict

But, if I run it in the code above in a conditional if else format, I get an error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'print("True")@LINE@else:@LINE@'
```

I am sure I have to be missing something simple?  I have tried using test_dict.get('some_key') which returns a:

result = {NoneType} None

I am not an expert at this point, obviously, but I'm also wouldn't consider myself a beginner.  And, what I may lack at this point in expertise I more than make up for finding the answers and solving the issue without ever having to ask almost 99% of the time.  This one I'm just not seeing.  Maybe I've been looking at it too long.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure it matters, but I am using PyCharm with Python 3.9.2

Comment: Have you tried pasting your code to repl.it and running it? Can you run a hexdump on the file to check if there are bad characters in it?

Comment: There is no problem with the code you posted. I don't understand the problem.What do you mean by "But, if I run it in the code above in a conditional if else format, I get an error:"

Comment: This is what I don't get.  The problem is when I'm running this in the debugger I'm getting the error.  I ran in repl.it and it's fine, so maybe something about the debugger session.

Comment: Nevermind, I think this has something to do with the debugger itself.  I'm not sure why it's returning this error.  Must be something weird with the app.

Answer (score 0):

This was something to do with the debugger I was using as the code appears to work fine as I expected it should and does.